# Help getting Scala 2.8 to work on Fedora 14 with Netbeans 6.9

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, fedora, netbeans-6.9, netbeans-plugins

I installed Scala 2.8 and NetBeans 6.9 on Fedora 14 (64-bit) by using repository versions (yum install scala netbeans). Then I downloaded Scala 2.8 plugin for Nb6.9 from source-forge. I installed it successfully by using Tools --> Plug-ins menus from NetBeans.

But now problem. When I start Scala project and try to compile little "helloworld" example (in order to see if compiler works), I get this:

/home/user/NetBeansProjects/ScalaApplication1/nbproject/build-impl.xml:42: You must set SCALA_HOME or environment property and append "-J-Dscala.home=scalahomepath"
                    property to the end of "netbeans_default_options" in NetBeansInstallationPath/etc/netbeans.conf to point to
                    Scala installation directory.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

I also noticed that Tools-->Scala Platforms show this 
http://i56.tinypic.com/110x72x.png

So probably that is part of the problem, too.

I searched for an answer prior asking here, but all tutorials seem to be outdated or dealing with completely another issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do what Netbeans tells you to do. This solves the problem. :-)

- Edit your .profile/.bashrc/.zshrc/... (whatever you use/prefer) and add an enviroment variable pointing to the directory with Scala in it.
- Edit your netbeans.conf and add "-J-Dscala.home=scalahomepath" to the end. (Be sure to replace "scalahomepath" with the actual path.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know where is scala installed. It has files in /usr/share/scala/lib , /usr/bin and maybe few other places. Also, if I set Scala Platfrom (from picture) to /usr/share/scala/lib, it says it isn't valid scala directory.